# How to change PasswordBox Control's foreground when it is disabled?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I want to change PasswordBox Control's foreground color when it is disabled? And how to create a style for it? or any other solution for it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the foreground colour like

```
if (!passWordBoxname.IsEnabled)
{
    passWordBoxname.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);// you can give your colour here
}
```

If the enable/disable property is changing dynamically, you can use make use of event IsEnabledChanged

Answer (score 1):

Set yourPasswodBox foreground like this no need to make style:

```
if(!yourPasswodBox.IsEnabled)
{
  yourPasswodBox.Foreground =GetColorFromHexa("#72C158");//You could Pass color value in hexa .
}
else
{
  yourPasswodBox.Foreground =GetColorFromHexa(your color value);
}
```

This method is used to pass any color value:

```
public SolidColorBrush GetColorFromHexa(string hexaColor)
       {
           byte R = Convert.ToByte(hexaColor.Substring(1, 2), 16);
           byte G = Convert.ToByte(hexaColor.Substring(3, 2), 16);
           byte B = Convert.ToByte(hexaColor.Substring(5, 2), 16);
           SolidColorBrush scb = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0xFF, R, G, B));
           return scb;
       }
```